# Why can't I accept both answers?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

In my question *[What does "do" mean in "What do I do"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/973/94)*, there are 2 answers that are helpful. But when I accept the other one the check mark goes away. Can I only accept one? I want to accept both.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users. What I would do is just commenting under a non-accepted one that it also has valuable information so that others did not hesitate to upvote it. P.S. Downvote here on Meta indicates my disagreement and does not change your reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only accept one answer, which is the one that helped you more than the other ones. This is by design.
If there are more than one answer that helped you, you can up-vote the ones that helped you, and accept the one that helped you more than the others; you could also assign a bounty to the other answers.

Even if it were possible to accept two answers, there would still be the problem when the answers that helped you are three; if it were possible to accept three answers, there would still be the problem when the answers that helped you are four.
IMO, accepting more than one answer would give to accepting an answer less importance than it actually has. In the case it would be possible to accept all the answers, accepting answers would completely lose its meaning. (What would accepting answers mean when all the given answers are marked as accepted?)

Comment: "If everyone gets to be special, then nobody is."

Comment: I disagree, several answers can be equally good. With a little ingenuity the problem can be solved. Or we can accept it's a flawed feature and go on, but recognize it is flawed first.

Comment: @Theta: I don't regard it as flawed. Sure, you can only pick one answer as the "best", but you can upvote as many as you want. More than once, an O.P. has left me a comment saying that my answer was very helpful, even though a different answer was selected as "best." Those instances never struck me as an injustice, a bad design, or a flaw in the system.

Comment: An example of my question where both answers are equally good:http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4023/what-are-the-little-legs-on-the-bottom-of-a-laptop-called

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that an accepted answer ought to be one that totally solves the problem, and is no worse than other answers.  This is much more objective than "best" or "most helpful". I have no problem with there being thirty accepted answers on some question, but only one on most questions. I would implement this feature request.