# Just Proposing To Implement Multi Best Answer Function

Tags: feature-request

[**Referring to this question**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/223055/if-at-all-what-would-this-phrase-mean-in-a-context) and answers I chose as best, when both answers seems (or are or multiple answers are correct to the OP (Or in case OP is not sure which one is best), I would like to propose implementing the multiple answers choice function. Can it be technically available or is my idea gonna be laughed off by many users just as something stupid?

kindly at least make a consideration. Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3421/9161 and https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/202/9161

Comment: Also related, on meta: [_Can I accept two answers?_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40200/can-i-accept-two-answers), _[Accepting more than one correct answer_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55305/accepting-more-than-one-correct-answer), and [_A way to accept more than one answer_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20063/a-way-to-accept-more-than-one-answer-would-be-useful).